# Linear vs. Non-linear Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Knowing that this is a quite basic question, I could not find the absolute answer for it on ChatGPT, hence decided to ask it on here.

Assuming that $f$ is a function of $x$ and $y$ and also that the function $f(x,y)$ is differentiable,is the following equation a linear one?

$$x \cdot \frac{df}{dx} + \frac{df}{dy} = 0$$

I got different answers for different phrasing of the question on ChatGPT.

First, it said that the following is **not** a linear **expression**:

$$x \cdot \frac{df}{dx}$$

Then, it said that the following is **not linear**:

$$x \cdot \frac{df}{dx} + \frac{df}{dy} = 0$$

It also said that the expression above is **not** a **linear equation** but a **partial differential equation**.

Then it said that the following equation is a **linear first-order partial differential equation**:

$$x \cdot \frac{df}{dx} + \frac{df}{dy} = 0$$

Asking the same question for the same equation, it stated that it is **not** a **linear equation**.

So what is the answer?

Is it possible that an expression (not an equation) being non-linear but an equation involving the same expression (without eliminating it somehow) being linear?

Is it possible for a linear differential equation to be a non-linear equation (is there such a thing)?

Thanks for your consideration and apologies for wasting your time :)

Kind regards,
NK

Comment: An equation is nonlinear if it contains terms in which the unknown function $f$ is multiplied either by itself or by its derivatives.

Comment: As you found, ChatGPT will tell you random nonsense. Don't rely on it for math knowledge, even just going on wikipedia is a better choice (but better: find a book).

Answer (score 0):

This is a hint: define

$$
L(f) := x \cdot \frac{df}{dx} + \frac{df}{dy}
$$

then your equation becomes $L(f) = 0$ where $L$ is a differential operator. The PDE being linear is equivalent to $L$ being linear, i.e., you want to check if the following is true

$$
\text{if }  f_1, f_2 \text{ solve } L(f) = 0, \text{ then an arbitrary linear combination  of }  f_1 \text{ and } f_2 \text{ solves } L(f) = 0.
$$

BTW: GPT is a decoder-only language model, it generates answers based on likelihood, ***NOT*** facts, i.e., it generates the next token (word) based on the previous combination of words' latent representation in an ultra high-dimensional space.